# proving that this map is not an isometry between the surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry

> Consider the parametrized surfaces
>   $$\phi(u,v)= (u\cos(v),u\sin(v),\log(u))$$
>   $$\psi(u,v)= (u\cos(v),u\sin(v),v)$$
>   Prove that the Gaussian curvature equals in both surfaces in each $(u,v)$. And then prove that $\psi \circ \phi^{-1}$ is not an isometry (i.e  the differential is not an isomorphism).

I proved that the Gaussian curvature are the same for both surfaces, but I'm struggling with the computation of the differential (or maybe there is another way to do it).

Answer (score -1):

Compute the corresponding first fundamental forms.

Comment: I already did that, what I'm asking is to prove that $\psi(\phi)$ is not an isometry )=

Comment: First, the derivative of $\psi\circ\phi^{-1}$ is always an isomorphism. You want it not to be an isometry. Show that if it were, the dot product of $\partial\phi/\partial u$ with itself woukd have to equal the dot product of $\partial\psi/\partial u$ with itself.